# Not understanding the purpose of the left shift in this problem

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm new to MIPs, and I have some confusion over the solution of this problem. I have attempted reading various sources and non of them really explained how the shifting was obtained or why its needed.

> For the following C statement, what is the corresponding MIPS assembly code? Assume that the
>   variables i, and j are assigned to registers $s3, and $s4, respectively. Assume that the base address of
>   the arrays A and B are in registers $s6 and $s7, respectively.
>
> Problem is: B[8] = A[i − j];

Solution is:

sub $t0, $s3, $s4

**sll $t0, $t0, 2**

add $t1, $s6, $t0

lw $t2, 0($t1)

sw $t2, 32($s7)

I don't understand why this left shift is needed after the subtraction of i and j. I understand that it shifts the result of i and j by 4 bits, but why is that needed?

Comment: Can you clarify which one of the MIPS registers that corresponds to the original code?

Comment: @Johan Ah. Sorry about that. Edited the problem in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left shift is needed to compute the offset of the item `A[i-j]`.

Every item of arrays A and B are 32-bit wide (4 bytes). But MIPS has byte addressing so each item of the array requires 4 addresses.

By shifting left 2 bits you are actually multiplying by 4. So (i-j) * 4 is the offset of the `i-j`'th item of the array.
That is also the reason for last line of your code `sw $t2, 32($s7)`, which stores the result in the 8th item of array, to use 32 as the offset.